# Extracting first 2 elements of table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a table in Mathematica as follows:

```
table1 = {{2,4,51,2017},{20,5,21,2018},{300,1,22,2016}}
```

From this, I was wondering how one could extract only the first 2 elements of each element to create a new table:

```
table2 = {{2,4}, {20,5}, {300,1}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `table1[[All,{1,2}`

Comment: `Take[table1, All, 2]`

Answer (score 4):

There are many possibilities, for instance,

```
table1[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
```

or

```
Take[table1, Length@table1, 2]
```

or

```
Transpose[Transpose[table1][[1 ;; 2]]]
```

or

```
Transpose@Take[Transpose@table1, 2]
```

or

```
#[[1 ;; 2]] & /@ table1
```

or

```
Take[#, 2] & /@ table1
```

all of which yield

```
(* {{2, 4}, {20, 5}, {300, 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use replace:

```
table1 //. {x_, y_, z1_, z2_} -> {x, y}
{{2, 4}, {20, 5}, {300, 1}}
```